# How to convert python Dictionary to JSON Dicitonary

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.x. I have a python dictionary

```
my_dict={'key1':'A12b','Key2':'cd12'}
```

I want to convert it in JSON format. I need it in this format

```
my_dict1={"key1":"A12b","Key2":"cd12"}
```

I tried `my_dict1=json.dumps(my_dict)` & I'm getting `'{"key1": "A12b", "Key2": "cd12"}'` which is of type `string`. Can you suggest me how do I convert?

Comment: It is not clear what you are expecting here. Python does not have a JSON dict datatype. JSON within Python is a string that can be sent to a web browser that is interpreted by javascript as a JSON object.

Comment: JSON is a serialization format. In other words, it's text with a certain format. In other words, JSON is a string. There is no "JSON dict".

Answer (score 0):

That is as close to JSON as you can get in Python. Send that object to a webserver and it will be interpreted as JSON which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` in `python` is a kind of **data structure**, while `json` is a kind of **data format**;

I suppose you want to convert a dict into a json-formated file? Then you should use `json.dump(obj, fp)` instead of `json.dumps(obj)`. The first one dumps a python dict `obj` to a file `fp`, and the second function make `obj` into a json formatted string.

In your case, to dump a dict `obj` into a file `example.json`, code it like below:

```
import json
my_dict={'key1':'A12b','Key2':'cd12'}
with open('example.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(my_dict, file)
```

Good luck!